# Calling Template Function with Multiple Parameter Values

Tags: c++, templates, non-type

I would like to call a template function `foo` with a sequence of different (non-type) parameters, taking consecutive integer values between a lower and upper bound. For instance:

```
template <int K> void foo(){ ... }

int const UPPER = 10, LOWER = 5;

for(int i = LOWER; i <= UPPER; i++)
    foo<i>();
```

This, of course, won't work since `i` is not known at compile time. I am looking for a way to achieve this sort of program without having to write something like:

```
foo<5>(); foo<6>(); foo<7>(); foo<8>(); foo<9>(); foo<10>();
```

This is in particular because I intend on changing  `UPPER` and `LOWER` from one execution to the next.

My only idea was to create a constant array of the integers which will be sent to the template parameter:

```
int const arr[6] = {5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10};

for(int i = LOWER; i <= UPPER; i++)
    foo<arr[i]>();
```

But, again, although the elements of the array are constant, `i` is not known at compile-time so neither is `arr[i]`. Any suggestions?

Thank you in advance.

Comment: It looks like you may want to use a [`std::integer_sequence`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/integer_sequence)

Comment: You might put foo() to a `template<int K> struct foowrapper`, that makes it a lot easier.. Is that allowed?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use two templates and `std::enable_if` to select one of them, depending on whether `Lower` is equal to `Upper`.
In case they *are* equal, we do nothing. Otherwise, we invoke `foo<Lower>()` and recurse with parameters `Lower + 1` and `Upper`.

```
template <int Lower, int Upper>
typename std::enable_if<Lower == Upper, void>::type callFoo()
{

}

template <int Lower, int Upper>
typename std::enable_if<Lower != Upper, void>::type callFoo()
{
    static_assert(Lower < Upper, "Lower must be less than or equal to Upper");

    foo<Lower>();
    callFoo<Lower + 1, Upper>();
}
```

Given this template, the following line will invoke `foo<K>()` for `K` values `5`, `6`, `7`, `8`, `9`, `10`.

```
callFoo<5, 11>();
```

Comment: Very elegant solution. Thank you.

Comment: Out of curiosity, do you know of any workarounds which could make this code compatible with older versions of C++ (prior to C++11)?

Answer (score 3):

You can make use of `std::integer_sequence` to get a compile-time list of numbers from 0 ascending and then add your offset:

```
// Here we take the lower bound and the sequence 0 to (Upper - Lower).
// We call foo with each number in the sequence added to the lower bound.
template<int Lower, int... Ints>
void call_foo_with_range_helper(std::integer_sequence<int, Ints...>) {
    // A common trick to expand the parameter pack without recursion or fold expressions
    (void)std::initializer_list<int>{(foo<Lower + Ints>(), 0)...};
}

// This simply makes it easier for the caller to use.
// We take the lower and upper bounds only.
template<int Lower, int Upper>
void call_foo_with_range() {
    call_foo_with_range_helper<Lower>(std::make_integer_sequence<int, Upper - Lower + 1>());
}   

int main() {
    int const UPPER = 10, LOWER = 5;

    call_foo_with_range<LOWER, UPPER>();
}
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I marked @TerraPass ' answer as best since I had an easier time understanding it (and I assume the people reading my code will too), but both are good solutions.

Comment: @TudorManole, No problem. The whole `initializer_list` business is unfortunate and once fold expressions are available, it can be replaced by `(foo<Lower + Ints>(), ...);`. Apart from that, `std::integer_sequence` is one of those things you tend to need a few times before you really appreciate it. In this case, the bulk of the work is supporting any range and not one starting at 0.

Answer (score 0):

As far as I know templates are resolved to actual structures during compile time, so you you will have to pass `int` as a argument to function.

Comment: The thing is that the OP knows the integers at compile time. It's a matter of having the equivalent of a compile-time loop that can use them as template arguments.

Comment: I know, but I didn't know something like this existed. @NathanOliver pointed at something I wasn't aware of, std::integer_sequence

Comment: @MaciekGrynda If I were able to pass the integers as arguments to the function, it would indeed make my life much easier. But I can't, for reasons which are beyond the scope of the question.

Comment: @chris "It's a matter of having the equivalent of a compile-time loop". +1.